# Read data from pipe and write to standard out with a delay in between. Must handle binary files too

Tags: linux, bash

I have been trying for about an hour now to find an elegant solution to this problem. My goal is basically to write a bandwidth control pipe command which I could re-use in various situations (not just for network transfers, I know about scp -l 1234). What I would like to do is:

1. Delay for `X` seconds.
2. Read `Y` amount (or less than Y if there isn't enough) data from pipe.
3. Write the read data to standard output.

Where:

- `X` could be `1..n`.
- `Y` could be 1 Byte up to some high value.

My problem is:

- It must support binary data which Bash can't handle well.

Roads I've taken or at least thought of:

- Using a `while read data` construct, it filters all white characters in the encoding your using.
- Using `dd bs=1 count=1` and looping. `dd` doesn't seem to have different exit codes for when there were something in `if` and not. Which makes it harder to know when to stop looping. This method should work if I redirect standard error to a temporary file, read it to check if something was transfered (as it's in the statistics printed on stderr) and repeat. But I suspect that it's extremely slow if used on large amounts of data and if it's possible I'd like to skip creating any temporary files.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to solve this as cleanly as possible using Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not much elegant but you can use some redirection trick to catch the number of bytes copied by dd and then use it as the exit condition for a while loop:

```
while [ -z "$byte_copied" ] || [ "$byte_copied" -ne 0 ]; do 
    sleep $X; 
    byte_copied=$(dd bs=$Y count=1 2>&1 >&4 | awk '$2 == "byte"{print $1}'); 
done 4>&1
```

However, if your intent is to limit the transfer throughput, I suggest you to use pv.

Comment: It looks very interesting. What does the `>&4` and `4>&1` do? I'll try your code out this evening. I'll also look at `pv`, the goal was to limit bandwidth and also learn new things.

Comment: At first, with 4>&1 the standard output of the while loop is stored in file descriptor 4; then with
    dd ... 2>&1 >&4 | ...
standard error of dd (where the number of transferred bytes is printed) is redirected to the pipe and the local standard output to file descriptor 4; 

I advise you to read this: http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/howto/redirection_tutorial

Answer (score 5):

may be **pv -qL RATE** ?

```
   -L RATE, --rate-limit RATE
          Limit the transfer to a maximum of RATE  bytes  per  second.   A
          suffix of "k", "m", "g", or "t" can be added to denote kilobytes
          (*1024), megabytes, and so on.
```

Comment: @karatedog stackoverflow is not personal consultant. Everyone benefits from answers even if doesn't get answered immediately. And the answer above has actually solved something to me.

Comment: I became much wiser in that 2.5 year since I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do it in bash? Can you just use an existing program such as [cstream](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/cstream.html)?

cstream meets your goal of a bandwidth controlled pipe command, but doesn't necessarily meet your other criteria with regard to your specific algorithm or implementation language.

Comment: Doing it in Bash has some upsides too (portability & no need for a separate application installation). But `cstream` looks like it will be highly useful to me. Nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

What about using `head -c` ?

```
cat /dev/zero | head -c 10 > test.out
```

Gives you a nice 10 bytes file.

Comment: It does. But my goal is to `read` from the pipe multiple times and put in a delay in between each `read`. `read` has no way of indicating if the pipe is empty, so that the reading loop may be braked. So I can't use `read`. But thank you for the suggestion!